# ARC Semantic Issue: No visible @interface for Class declares the selector

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, class-method

Pretty basic stuff but i am unable to troubleshoot where the problem is. In my project, i have a class named "TheFeedStore" with following two methods:

```
- (BOOL)hasItemBeenRead:(RSSItem *)item
{
   ............
}

- (void)markItemAsRead:(RSSItem *)item
{
  .........
}
```

I am using the following class method so other classes can access these methods using it:

```
+ (TheFeedStore *) sharedStore
{
    static TheFeedStore *feedStore = nil;

    if (!feedStore) {
        feedStore = [[TheFeedStore alloc] init];
    }
    return feedStore;
}
```

In one of my another class, i can easily access the above methods by writing

```
if ([[TheFeedStore sharedStore] hasItemBeenRead:item])
```

or

```
[[TheFeedStore sharedStore] markItemAsRead:entry];
```

But in another class if i try to access these methods in a similar manner, i get the error "No visible @interface for 'TheFeedStore' declares the selector 'hasItemBeenRead:"

> 1) I have imported TheFeedStore.h file in the classes from i am
>   accessing these methods of TheFeedStore class.
>
> 2) I have checked like 10 times and there is no typo.
>
> 3) The methods i am accessing are also declared in the header file of
>   TheFeedStore.h

**UPDATE:** Just to check, i have declared another test method in TheFeedStore.h, same result, one class can access the newly created method while rest of the three classes cannot.

**UPDATE:** I have tried creating more methods in the TheFeedStore.h just for troubleshooting this issue. The new methods are also not accessible from the other classes. But if the return type of these new methods is (RSSChannel*) which is another model class in my project, than they become accessible. If their return type is other than some class like (void) and (BOOL) then they are not accessible. Here is my TheFeedStore.h https://gist.github.com/jessicamoore112/5558473

Comment: Did you `#import` the class into the class where you are getting this error?

Comment: of course i have imported the class. It does not recognize the methods, even "sharedStore" class method comes in the autocomplete list when i type [[TheFeedStore sharedStore]

Comment: what do you have in TheFeedStore.h file ? Have you declared these instance methods in .h ?

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama yes these methods are declared in the header file as well

Comment: @AJ112 just checking. Out of curiosity is it one class that does not get the error and many that do, or is it the other way around?

Comment: @MichaelReneer One class can access these methods while rest of the three classes cannot.

Comment: Do you `#import` any of other classes in `TheFeedStore.h` file ?

Comment: Those lines in the other three classes are exactly the same??  Arguments and everything?

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama yes i have imported the header files

Comment: @borrrden yes they are exactly the same, in fact i have tried copy and paste but it didn't work

Comment: No i mean inside your `TheFeedStore.h` class, do you import otherclasses.h ?

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama why would i import other classes in TheFeedStore.h if what i am doing is accessing from other classes the methods of TheFeedStore??? it doesn't make any sense, but just to check i have tried that as well but it didn't work

Comment: He was confirming that you weren't doing that, not suggesting that you should.

Comment: Yes you don't have to import other .h files in TheFeedStore.h file. I asked because if you have imported them by mistake, then there can be problems like this. I just asked to clarify.

Comment: By any chance do you have a circular import cycle?  That is, TheFeedStore.h imports files which import TheFeedStore.h?

Comment: @borrrden i have re-checked and there is no import cycle.

Comment: Try these: (1) In TheFeedStore.h, next to the declaration of -hasItemBeenRead:, add `#error declaration` and recompile. You should get "error: declaration" as a compiler error. If you don't there's a problem such as circular includes or two copies of TheFeedStore.h. (2) Use Xcode's Product > Generate Output > Preprocessed File command on the .m file that gets the error. This will show you the code as it looks after performing the #imports and #defines. You should be able to find your call site, and then find the method declarations on some line before the call site.

Comment: @GregParker 1) yes i received the compile error when i added #error declaration. 2) BUT i pre-processed file option is not accessible, its dimmed out

Comment: Also i am using @class instead of #import in my header files so i don't know how circular loop has built of even if its there

Comment: @AJ11 Post the header file for the singleton class

Comment: @HannesSverrisson here is the header file https://gist.github.com/jessicamoore112/5558473

Comment: @GregParker When i use the Preprocess file option, the error goes away and it presents me with a long file. Running the program again brings the error back

Comment: I looked at the header and see you declare \@class RSSChannel;
\@class RSSItem; in it. But you declare the other files first so you should only declare the TheFeedStore in the implementation files of RSSChannel and RSSItem, #import "TheFeedStore.h"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have said that you are using @class instead of #import in your header files, the methods that you are trying to access are declared in the header files and there are no typos of any kind.

In such cases, usually no body points this issue but i am going to do it anyway because i have faced such issues many times. You have probably created many copies of your project to work on each functionality and also keeping a working project.

When you do this, sometimes Xcode is still using the older copies of few files. That means it is still using the older copy of the TheFeedStore.h when the methods you are trying to access were not declared by you.

How to solve this problem is very simple. Go to the file from which you are trying to access the methods and the files in which these methods are declared.

In the Utilities section on the right hand side, check the location and full path under "Identity and Type" area.

First check the names of the project, if it is different from the project name that you are working on, that means Xcode is still pulling the old copies of the files from the previous revision of your project. See the blue arrows where the project name is 13SampleMoreRequests in my case.

[image: utilities]

If this name is same as your project name, then my answer does not solve your problem. If its different, you should use the new copies of the file by browsing the new location using the sign that is pointed out by red arrow.

Once you browse and use the new files, your problem will be solved and you will be able to access the methods. If you still can't, copy these files, delete from the project and then add them again and you won't face this problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is very good suggestion:) it doesnt resolve my problem though:) but at least points that this error may be resulted by (here put proper description) XCode. In project tree I have a class with methods up-to-date, but when I jump from the import statement in class where the error occurred then it takes me to some old version of class - and "Not Applicable" displayed in the Utilities panel.

Answer (score 2):

Cyclical imports, e.g. `A.h` imports `B.h` while also `B.h` imports `A.h` is the most common problem.

In C, cyclical imports won't work and one of the imports will be silently ignored. Make sure you are not having a cyclical import. If you do, solve it (e.g. using forward declarations).

Import problems can be also easily inspected if you generate the preprocessed output (you can find it in one of the Xcode menus).

Comment: 1) I am using the forward declaration instead of import statements. 2) In Product > Generate Output there is this option for pre-proceed file but it generated an extremely long file and i don't know how to check it for my issue

Comment: When i use the Preprocess file option, the error goes away and it presents me with a long file. Running the program again brings the error back

Comment: @AJ112 Maybe you should first learn how preprocessor, especially imports & includes work.

Answer (score 1):

That might sound silly, but I have similar cases once in a while and sometimes just simple quitting and starting xcode helps, it tends to stuck sometimes.
Also, sometimes cleaning the project helps.
'Cause I have very similar to yours singleton code and it works fine.

Comment: i have cleaned, restarted xcode, reset the simulator, it didn't work. As you said "that might sound silly" :D

Comment: Maybe u can upload the part of your project somewhere so I could take a look at it?

Comment: i have added the code of singleton class here https://gist.github.com/jessicamoore112/5558473

Comment: It looks ok as for me, but it doesn't tell much. I'd rather see more code to try this, both .h and .m files of singleton and the classes where you use it. Maybe you can upload the part of your project that doesn't work or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Guys I had encountered the exact same issues. After some searching on SO and the search engine I was able to solve it.

In my Case I have four files:

- RadioStation.h
- RadioStation.m
- ViewController.h
- ViewController.m

My mistake was to place all my methods in RadioStation.m and only put my variables on radioStation.h
So when I import radioSation.h on my  ViewController.m and try to  define methods for button-click on my app that's where the problems started. 
I got the error/warnings  "ARC Semantic Issue: No visible @interface for Class declares the selector" every time I built or ran the app simulator.

My Solution was to go back to RadioStation.h file and just declare all my methods there.
Since they were already defined on RadioStation.m I was good to go.

So make sure you have properly declared your methods on the file that is going to be imported on your viewControllers.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had some very strange path entries in

- Framework Search Paths
- Library Search Path

(Targets -> YOUR_APP_NAME -> Build Settings in "Search Paths" section)

I removed them and the error messages are gone.