# Xcode Preprocessed File Troubleshooting Circular Import Loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am using Xcode 4.6.2 and i believe i am facing circular import issue in my project which i am unable to troubleshoot. Due to which i am not able to access few methods from another class using the class method. See my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431902/arc-semantic-issue-no-visible-interface-for-class-declares-the-selector).

Although i am using @class instead of #import in my header files, still i am unable to fine where exactly the problem is. Members of the StackOverflow have suggested me to use Xcode's built in functionality found under Product > Generate Output > Preprocessed File.

I have used this functionality and it generated a file that is too long to follow and i don't know what to do with it.

I have tried searching how to use it to troubleshoot the issue but couldn't find much help. Can anyone help me point out how to use "Preprocessed File" to troubleshoot my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Preprocessed File has never been particularly useful in situations like these. Are you defining your own protocols? Usually including those can cause circular reference issues.

Comment: @DanFairaizl no there are no protocol files in the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also went through your earlier question you have mentioned inside the question. You have said that you are using @class instead of #import in your header files, the methods that you are trying to access are declared in the header files and there are no typos of any kind.

In such cases, usually no body points this issue but i am going to do it anyway because i have faced such issues many times. You have probably created many copies of your project to work on each functionality and also keeping a working project.

When you do this, sometimes Xcode is still using the older copies of few files. That means it is still using the older copy of the TheFeedStore.h when the methods you are trying to access were not declared by you.

How to solve this problem is very simple. Go to the file from which you are trying to access the methods and the files in which these methods are declared.

In the Utilities section on the right hand side, check the location and full path under "Identity and Type" area.

First check the names of the project, if it is different from the project name that you are working on, that means Xcode is still pulling the old copies of the files from the previous revision of your project. See the blue arrows where the project name is 13SampleMoreRequests in my case.

[image: utilities section]

If this name is same as your project name, then my answer does not solve your problem. If its different, you should use the new copies of the file by browsing the new location using the sign that is pointed out by red arrow.

Once you browse and use the new files, your problem will be solved and you will be able to access the methods. If you still can't, copy these files, delete from the project and then add them again and you won't face this problem.

Hope this helps!