# Objective C instance methods not found

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a class called Datahandler with 2 methods. In my LoginViewController, I can use them, but in another ViewController they cannot be found.

This is my DataHandler.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataHandler : NSObject

- (int) loginOnServer:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password;

- (NSString *) getJsonFromServer;


@end
```

In my LoginViewController, both methods are found.

LoginViewController.m:

```
#import "DataHandler.h"
...

@interface LoginViewController ()

...

@end

@implementation LoginViewController



- (void) checkLogin:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *) password
{
    DataHandler *dataHandler = [[DataHandler alloc] init];

    int result = [dataHandler loginOnServer:email password:password];

    ...
}

...

@end
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
#import "DataHandler.h"
...    

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    DataHandler *dh = [[DataHandler alloc] init];

    NSString *json = [dh getJsonFromServer];

    ...

}
```

What I get there is:

```
FirstViewController.m:32:23: No visible @interface for 'DataHandler' declares the selector 'getJsonFromServer'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Edit 1:

There was another old class called DataHandler in my project folder, which was used instead of the this one.

Comment: I've looked long and hard and can see no error.

Comment: me neither... weird error.. have you done a clean? maybe some old file is stuck somewhere.... no idea

Comment: Are things working now?

Comment: Check This [Link You will definitely find your answer here ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431902/arc-semantic-issue-no-visible-interface-for-class-declares-the-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please delete your or rename your another DataHandler file and give the reference in your buildPhases (Compile sources)

As you can see log is showing no visible interface that means definition of method is not available in your another DataHandler.h, therefore receiver isn't able to get the declaration of your method.