# No visible @interface for class declares the selector iPhone issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

So I have this code in my app delegate.m -

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"

- (NSOperationQueue *) getOperationQueue
{
    if(queue == nil){
        queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    }

    return queue;
}
```

this is my app delegate.h-

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property NSOperationQueue *queue;

- (NSOperationQueue*) getOperationQueue;

@end
```

in another file I have something like this-

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AJAXUtils.h"

+ (void)getAsyncJsonWithUrl:(NSURL *)url callback:(void (^)(NSDictionary*))callbackFunction
{    
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    @try{
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
                                           queue:[appDelegate getOperationQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, 
                                     NSData *data, NSError *error){
            //more code
        }

        //more code 

    }
```

I'm getting an error - "No visible @interface for AppDelegate declares the selector 'getOperationQueue'

Not really sure why - can anyone tell me?

Comment: Huh, weird one. Do you have another AppDelegate.h that might be being #imported instead?

Comment: Please show all your #imports for all related files.

Comment: well...they're in different folders? So I guess they're in different projects and that shouldn't matter?

Comment: 0x7fff... what other imports would be helpful?

Comment: Are you getting any other warnings?

Comment: ah I'm getting a method definition for getOperationQueue not found

Comment: oh wait that was because I had it in the interface as I tried to work around it by just having the method in the class, which can't happen

Comment: this question was answered by the answer for this - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431902/arc-semantic-issue-no-visible-interface-for-class-declares-the-selector?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think, typecasting should work:

> appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
>   delegate];