# ARC Semantic Issue in Unity build

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode8

I encountered such a problem when building on a project with unity in xcode. When you run a project in xcode, it produces such errors.
[error in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGcZq.png)

I use xcode 8. Someone faced a similar? I will be glad to any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARC Semantic Issue: No visible @interface for Class declares the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431902/arc-semantic-issue-no-visible-interface-for-class-declares-the-selector)

Comment: This post don`t help.

Comment: Which specific version of Unity and Xcode? What plugins? Go find your editor.log file and copy/paste the error lines as text in the question.

Comment: version Unity 2017.2, Xcode 8.0, Facebook SDK for unity 7.11.0